# Python: Getting KeyError: 'Corrections' error when attempting to run GingerIt spell checker on 600+ characters

Tags: python-3.x

Currently working on a text re-writter application in python 3.7 for which I need a spell-checker. Trying to use [Gingerit](https://pypi.org/project/gingerit/) for it which gives great result for samples but on running it for more than 600+ characters i get the following error:

[error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrcHu.png)

My code is as follows:

from gingerit.gingerit import GingerIt

```
text = 'Overview At Emburse our mission is to help make our users’ lives — and their businesses – better.We are dramatically transforming how organizations manage corporate expenses and invoices. We humanize work by automating manual tasks and saving users’ time, so they can focus on what matters most — their family, community, or more rewarding work.We help CFO’s give their employees a simple and amazing experience while ensuring.compliance and reducing costs. Our solutions are tailored for companies from start-ups to enterprises. We have more than 14,000 clients and 4.5 million users globally. Embue '

print(len(text))
parser = GingerIt()
result=parser.parse(text)

print(result)
```

Any insight will be much appreciated.
Rgds

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem of your text .I will give an example to clarify the subject:
example : this code see text:

```
from gingerit.gingerit import GingerIt

text = 'The smelt of fliwers bring back memories.'

def tx (txt):
    parser = GingerIt()
    return(parser.parse(txt))
 
print(tx(text))
```

This code is run without problems but because your text has several parts, you must first separate them this code see:

```
from gingerit.gingerit import GingerIt
text = 'Overview At Emburse our mission is to help make our users’ lives — and their businesses – better.We are dramatically transforming how organizations manage corporate expenses and invoices. We humanize work by automating manual tasks and saving users’ time, so they can focus on what matters most — their family, community, or more rewarding work.We help CFO’s give their employees a simple and amazing experience while ensuring.compliance and reducing costs. Our solutions are tailored for companies from start-ups to enterprises. We have more than 14,000 clients and 4.5 million users globally. Embue '
text1 =text.strip()
# text = 'The smelt of fliwers bring back memories.'

def tx (txt):
    parser = GingerIt()
    return(parser.parse(txt))
 
print(tx(text1))
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add strip in the text

result=parser.parse(text.strip())